# What is the appropriate wood glue for outdoor wood furniture?

Tags: glue

I have been considering building an outdoor bench.

What is a good wood glue for outdoor wood furniture?

Comment: I've used Titebond 3 on a cedar box; after 2 years it's holding fine; no issues what so ever.  Where I live temperature varies from 30C (86F) to -30C (-22F).

Comment: Second Titebond 3. Outdoor use is one of its main purposes.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are a number of waterproof adhesives you can use on wood. This includes waterproof versions of conventional "carpenter's glue", polyurethane adhesives (e.g. the original Gorilla glue), urea-formaldehyde adhesive (e.g. Cascamite) and epoxies as well.

Each has advantages and disadvantages but they're all reliably waterproof.

**Note on strength:** there is *no* significant strength advantage to any of these despite much written to the contrary. While there are stronger and weaker ones in this list the 'weakest' of them will still make joints that are stronger than the wood itself, which of course is more than strong enough for furniture.

This assumes the joints are formed correctly and appropriate clamp pressure is applied.